# Example of Login with Tiktok (web) flow

Tags: oauth, tiktok

I would like a user to login with tikok on the web and get his basic information like:

- `avarat_url`
- `union_id` (uniq user identifier provided by tiktok)
- `display_name`

The [Tiktok Login Kit for Web Documentation](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-web) seems to be missing a full example on how to implement the full sequence of calls. Also some things are not explained at all (like the callback URL). Can someone share their full solution with code example on how to integrate tiktok login onto a webpage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Heres a full example of the tiktok login for web implementation:

1. setup a tiktok developer account https://developers.tiktok.com/
2. create a new app, this will generate a `CLIENT_KEY` and `CLIENT_SECRET`.
3. create 2 backend endpoints that you control, for example:

   - https://example.com/auth : builds a tiktok URL and redirects the user to that endpoint (where the user will be prompted to login).
   - https://example.com/authCallback : once the user has finished the login with tiktok flow, tiktok sends an authorizationResponse to this endpoint. The authorizationResponse contains info that you need to fetch the users data.
4. in section "**Platform Info**": insert the `callback URL` and `redirect domain`. The **callback URL** being the second of the 2 server endpoints listed above. Tiktok will send the authorizationResponse to that URL once the user successfully loggs in and grants or declines the required permissions. In **redirect domain** simply add the domain without the exact path.
   [image: Platform info]
5. fill out all info for your app and wait for approval, this can take up to 1-3 days.
6. once approved, you are ready to implement the full flow, which consists of multiple steps/requests.

   **(A)** send the user from your frontend to your first backend endpoint `https://example.com/auth`. From there, the user will be redirected to the tiktok auth page.

   **(B)** once the user finished the authorization, tiktok sends a authorizationResponse to your callback URL (`https://example.com/authCallback`), which contains a variable `code`. With the `code` you can request the `access_token` and `open_id` of the user.

   **(C)** use the `access_token` and `open_id` to request basic user info.

#### (A) Send User to Tiktok Authentication Page

In your frontend, redirect the user to `https://example.com/auth`. Then run the following nodejs backend code on your `/auth` route. For this example we use an **express** app (`req` = request object, `res` = response object):

```js
// IMPORTANT, it is your responsibility to store a csrf token
// in your database, to be able to prevent xss attacks, read more
// here (section 2.1) =>  https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-web
const createCsrfState = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
const csrfState = createCsrfState(); 
res.cookie('csrfState', csrfState, { maxAge: 60000 });

let url = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/';

url += `?client_key=${CLIENT_KEY}`;
url += '&scope=user.info.basic';
url += '&response_type=code';
url += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent('https://example.com/authCallback')}`;
url += '&state=' + csrfState;

// redirect the user to the generated URL
// user will be prompted to login with tiktok
// and authorize needed permissions
res.redirect(url);
```

This code redirects the user to a tiktok url, where the user is prompted to sign in with tiktok and grant access.
[image: user is prompted to login]

#### (B) Handle `authorizationResponse`, use `code` to get `access_token` and `open_id`

Once the user finished the login process, tiktok sends an authorizationResponse to your second backend server endpoint https://example.com/authCallback. In that callback you recieve variables `state` and `code`.

```js
// express example with
// `req` = request object
// `res` = response object

// check if the csrf token is valid
// its the developers responsibility
// to setup a validation logic.
if (!validateCsrfToken(req.query.state)) {
  throw new Error("invalid csrf token");
}

async function getAccessTokenAndOpenId(code, TIKTOK_CLIENT_KEY, TIKTOK_CLIENT_SECRET) {
  let urlAccessToken = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/oauth/access_token/';
  urlAccessToken += '?client_key=' + TIKTOK_CLIENT_KEY;
  urlAccessToken += '&client_secret=' + TIKTOK_CLIENT_SECRET;
  urlAccessToken += '&code=' + code;
  urlAccessToken += '&grant_type=authorization_code';
  const resp = await axios.post(urlAccessToken);
  return {
    accessToken: resp.data.data.access_token,
    openId: resp.data.data.open_id,
  };
}

const code = req.query.code;
const { openId, accessToken } = await getAccessTokenAndOpenId(code, TIKTOK_CLIENT_KEY, TIKTOK_CLIENT_SECRET);
```

#### (C) Get `basic user info`

```js
async function getBasicInfo(accessToken, openId) {
  let urlBasicInfo = `https://open-api.tiktok.com/user/info/`;
  const data = {
    access_token: accessToken,
    open_id: openId,
    fields: [
      "open_id",
      "union_id",
      "avatar_url",
      "avatar_url_100",
      "avatar_url_200",
      "avatar_large_url",
      "display_name",
    ],
  };
  const resp = await axios.post(urlBasicInfo, data);
  return resp.data.data.user;
}

const userBasicInfo = await getBasicInfo(accessToken, openId);
//  done!
```

Comment: it does not return the user email? :( too bad https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-user-info-basic

Comment: No email is returned to my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! 
Either I am blind or the web page is bugged? On step 2 I create a new App for the TikTok Login Kit. But there is no CLIENT_SECRET or CLIENT_KEY shown. I only get shown the App which is in status "In progress". 

Will the secret show after I get approved by the review?

Comment: @robinryf yes you get the keys once approved I belive.

Comment: what about user followers and most importantly, their handle/username?

Comment: is it not possible to test this localhost?